# Python Attribute Error Raised while using Thumbnail method of PIL

Tags: python

I am using PIL to make an application to open all images in a folder. I sought for tutorials for PIL. I tried to find tutorials with list of images, but I failed to do so. I found some, but I had to list the file location beforehand. It annoyed me. So, instead I want the user to choose a folder, and the application would load all the images for the user. But, while making the thumbnails for the list of images, I got an error which I'm not familiar with. This is the exact error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
1892, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "f:\OG\Python\ImageViewer.py", line 47, in openFolder
GetFiles()
File "f:\OG\Python\ImageViewer.py", line 87, in GetFiles
with Image.open(i) as img:
prefix = fp.read(16)
raise AttributeError(name)
```

The minimal code to get this error is:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

fileDir = "Your Folder"
imageList = []
image_list = []

for filename in glob.glob(fileDir + '/*.jpg'): # gets jpg
    im = Image.open(filename)
    imageList.append(im)

for i in imageList:
    with Image.open(i) as img: # This raises the error
        imageList[i] = img.thumbnail((550, 450))

for i in image_list: # Would this work?
    image_list[i] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageList[i])
```

I would like to know if the code that is commented with 'Would this work?' would work or not.

Comment: You can find out if the code that is commented with "would this work" would work by executing it and observing the results.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I would love to, but I get an error before I could do that :(

Comment: Then it would not work. Or is your actual question why you get an error? That's because you are passing an `Image` object to `Image.open`, instead of a filename.

Comment: @mkrieger1 well, at least I got to know if it would or not

Comment: remove `im = Image.open(filename)` from first loop and see what happen. Just append filenames to the list, you are opening them in second loop anyway

Comment: @w8eight Then I get  this error:- TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the reading part again which doesn't make sense

```
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

fileDir =r"your path"
imageList = []

for filename in glob.glob(fileDir + '/*.jpg'): # gets jpg
    im = Image.open(filename)
    imageList.append(im)
```

`imageList` will look like this :

```
[<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=200x200 at 0x25334A87D90>]
```

#### here is the blockbuster solution

```
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import PIL
from pathlib import Path

fileDir = r"your_path_here"
imageList = []

for filename in glob.glob(fileDir + '/*.jpg'):  # gets jpg
    im = Image.open(filename)
    imageList.append(im)
    im.thumbnail((550, 450))
    im.save(fileDir+'/'+Path(filename).name.split('.')[0]+'_thumbnail.png')
```

Comment: I still get the error :(

Comment: the same error ? @AnimeShinjas

Comment: Yes. But, Am I supposed to do something other than my code in the Process method? P.S I renamed the processedImage with image because I got a Not Defined error

Comment: hey @AnimeShinjas updated the answer, this will save the thumbnails as you want in the same folder

Comment: Damn. I actually don't want to save the image. But, thanks for the effort, I'll try to edit my code on my own from here :)

Comment: No worries @AnimeShinjas, let me know if you got anything again/ or need to flow from this point of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241035/discussion-between-anime-shinjas-and-tamil-selvan).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I edited the code as follows:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

fileDir = "Your Folder"
imageList = []
image_list = []
count = 0

for filename in glob.glob(fileDir + '/*.jpg'): # gets jpg
    imageList.append(filename)

for i in imageList:
    with Image.open(i) as img:
    i = img.thumbnail((550, 450))

for i in imageList: # This gives a Key Error Now
    image_list.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageList[count]))
    count = count + 1
```

Basically, Introduced a new variable count with a value of 0, removed open from first for loop, used append method for the last for loop and added count 1 each time :)

Comment: Hey, your first loop will not do anything except you save the thumbnail object to the `i`. You are not appending anything to the,`imageList` and it will give you an index error since it is an empty list and how can you declare this as a solved issue and accepted answer.

Comment: @TamilSelvan I am so sorry for seeing it this late. I do not use stack overflow often, but I will remove the first loop :D